# how much of a web site security along with server security?

Tags: asp.net, security

I write a phrase and please you say your point of view about it:

**For my web site,If My Server Is Secure(Server Admin warranty that) and I prevent XSS and Sql Injenction attack,Is my web site secure?**

*(please leave your answer with reference)*

Thanks

**Edit 1 :**:
every of above items + `Cross-site request forgery`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, don't expect to obtain a "secure" end state as if it's an absolute position - you can't. Software security is about *reducing* risk and you won't ever reach a position of *no* risk.

There are many, many other risks you've missed: broken authentication and session management, insecure direct object references, security misconfiguration, insecure cryptographic storage, failure to restrict URL access, insufficient transport layer protection and unvalidated redirects and forwards to name a few. These are all out of the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project) and I suggest you start with these.

Make sure you understand:

1. The risk
2. How it's exploited
3. How you can protect against it

If you'd like to see all this in the context of ASP.NET have a read through the [OWASP Top 10 for .NET developers series](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/05/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-1.html#).

And thee are risks beyond these top 10 too, they're just the most common ones in web apps.

Answer (score 1):

No. There are other attack methods. For example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: I think this sort of attack can prevented by DON'T Using of Query Strings

Comment: All attacks can be prevented. It's a question of whether you have. Chances are, your code has a vulnerability, because most code has some. Security isn't really a "secure or not" kind of thing, it's more "how secure is it?" spectrum.

Comment: CSRF exploits are also vulnerable to POST requests, it's not just query strings in a get request. Have a look at the example here: http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-5.html